# How to sequentially populate a list of given length from another list of elements and recursively find all possible combinations that satisfy?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a seed list *lst* of the form ['missing', 'missing, 'missing', 'missing', 'missing']. I want to sequentially (and alternatively) fill it by sampling from another list *samples* of the form ['e1', 'e2'].

Effectively, I want to fill *lst* sequentially until either all elements are filled with *samples* (alternatively picking e1 and e2, always starting from e1) or a stopping condition is met. One set of steps would lead to one such combination, and I would recursively like to find all.

More concretely, consider the following example.

Combination Example 1:

```
0: ['missing', 'e1, 'missing', 'missing', 'missing']
1: ['missing', 'e1, 'e2', 'missing', 'missing']
2: ['missing', 'e1, 'e2', 'missing', 'e1']
3: ['missing', 'e1, 'e2', 'e2', 'e1']
4: ['e1', 'e1, 'e2', 'e2', 'e1']
```

As you can see, by step 4 the entire list is populated. This is one possible combination and I would like to generate every combination possible, step by step.

Here is another illustration. Notice, like before, 'e1' and 'e2' are alternatively selected, with 'e1' always slected first. Combination Example 2:

```
0: ['e1', 'missing, 'missing', 'missing', 'missing']
1: ['e1', 'e2, 'missing', 'missing', 'missing']
2: ['e1', 'e2, 'e1', 'missing', 'missing']
3: ['e1', 'e2, 'e2', 'e2', 'missing']
4: ['e1', 'e2, 'e1', 'e2', 'e1']
```

Other than the 'entire list is filled', I might have an arbitrary termination check at each step of the generation process (for any given combination we are trying). For instance, if check_termination(current_lst) is satisfied for a given step in any one of the combinations, then I would to break the recursion and move on to the next combination. What is an efficient, pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess this is a simplified MWE so I'm not sure whether this helps, but it might be easier to construct all possible end states. In that case the translation of the intermediate interrupt criterion would be the hard work.

Comment: Interesting, David. MWE?

Comment: A [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. an abstract version of what you actually will do with it :)

Comment: Ah ok. No, constructing all possible end states don't work since there are multiple ways of getting to the same end state

Comment: That's not a problem, converting the lists to tuples, for example, and using `set()` you can get unique end results. The question is whether there is a way to see which paths are going to be blocked or more precisely to which element *all* paths are going to be blocked.

Comment: What I'm saying is we don't want unique end results. We want all possible combinations, even though a lot of them would lead to the same end states. The sequence of steps is what should be unique. But yes, going back to the original question, we do want there to be a way to terminate early in the process of getting to an end state.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I constructed this but I am pretty sure this will scale catastrophically. However, that might be intrinsic to the question (I replaced `'missing'` by `''`)

```
length = 5
lsts = {tuple(): ['' for _ in range(length)]}
intr_lsts = []
sample = 'e1'
for _ in range(length):
    new_lsts = {}
    for filled, lst in lsts.items():
        empty = set(range(length))-set(filled)
        for e in empty:
            new_filled = filled+tuple([e])
            new_lst = list(lst)
            new_lst[e] = str(sample)
            if interrupt_criterion(new_lst):
                intr_lsts.append(new_lst)
            else:
                new_lsts[new_filled] = new_lst
    sample = 'e1' if sample=='e2' else 'e2'
    lsts = new_lsts
out = list(lsts.values())+intr_lsts
#out = set(tuple(v) for v in out) # In case you want unique lists in output
print(out)
```

`interupt_criterion` needs to be a callable on a list (e.g. a lambda) for this, but you can of course just change that.